# How to pass values to a Gitlab CI Job

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab ci job to download and build few files and then publish to another server. I have done a POC and was successful. The problem is that I would like to customize the job when triggered manually or via API. How can i pass the dynamic values(user given) to reflect in CI job (like a filename, format etc)?

I am using Windows runner.

I saw trigger variables and environment variables but can be retrieved while execution once the value is set in UI. I want a bit different where I will get the values from user.

Is it not possible in GitLab?

Edit:

A bit more info on how I'm using the pipeline. My pipeline has two stages - build and deploy. I want the build to run once, but I want to be able to call deploy multiple to deploy to different server. I can use the variable to determine to which server I want to deploy. Through GitLab UI this is possible - i can set variables for pipeline and also for job that overrides the pipeline variable. I just want to do the same thing through API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass variables when starting a pipeline: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#run-a-pipeline-manually

> Pipelines can be manually executed, with predefined **or manually-specified variables**.

These variables can be also specified on the API call: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline

> An array containing the variables available in the pipeline, matching the structure [{ ‘key’ => ‘UPLOAD_TO_S3’, ‘value’ => ‘true’ }]

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that I would like to customize the job when triggered manually or via API

This should be possible with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#specify-variables-when-running-manual-jobs-via-the-api) (March 2022)

> ### Specify variables when running manual jobs via the API
>
> When running a manual job, it can be useful to input CI/CD variables to overwrite the existing variables, or to add new ones.
>
> Previously, the only way to do this, was to do it through the UI.
>
> In this release we’ve added the ability to specify variables when running a job by using the REST API, which will give you more options for automating your CI/CD pipelines.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#run-a-job) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/37267).

Example:

```sh
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/1/play
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>"
     --data @variables.json
```

`@variables.json` is structured like:

```json
{
  "job_variables_attributes": [
    {
      "key": "TEST_VAR_1",
      "value": "test1"
    },
    {
      "key": "TEST_VAR_2",
      "value": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @sgm What GitLab version are you using? `variables.json` is a file to be created and passed as parameter to your curl command. It is not a file "to be received", but "to be sent". See also "[What does the `@` (at) symbol before a filename mean in a `curl` command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144483/7490)"

Comment: im using 14.09.1-ee version. I send variables.json with @ but not appears the TEST_VAR_! in the job. I used the example code

Comment: @sgm Strange. Can you illustrate that in a new separate question?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript example of passing variables to a job via GitLab API

If you're *not using curl*, but want to trigger a GitLab job with variables via API programmatically from your language of choice, the important part to make `job_variables_attributes` work is setting correct `Content-Type`:

Example in JavaScript / nodejs:

```js
const https = request('https')

const postData = JSON.stringify({
    job_variables_attributes: [
       {
            key: 'CUSTOM_VAR1',
            value: 'test1',
        },
        {
            key: 'CUSTOM_VAR2',
            value: 'test2',
        },
    ],
});


const req = https.request({    
    method: 'POST', 
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com',
    path: `/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/jobs/${jobId}/play?private_token=${token}`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
}, (res) => ...)

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Then in the job you should have `$CUSTOM_VAR1` and `$CUSTOM_VAR2`.